# Stack Overflow should add a "Skip to content" button for Accessibility

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, accessibility

Many websites include a skip to content button which is activated when the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed for the (usually) first time, like in Google:

[image]

Or GitHub:

[image]

**Why**:

The goal of this button is to provide non-mouse users a functionality to skip the first repetitive links which usually are already known to the user, i.e.: the nav, header links, and to make their navigation by keyboard easier and more pleasant.

More info on [Skip to main content](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/it-accessibility-at-nc-state/developers/accessibility-handbook/mouse-and-keyboard-events/skip-to-main-content/).

Comment: Just looking at this question page as an example, there are 18 tabstops to be tabbed through before I get to the content of the question. This would need to be performed upon every page navigation. I can see how this would be a very useful feature for anyone who is using a screenreader / navigating by keyboard, and necessary for the a11y of SO and StackExchange in general.

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315634/369403)

Comment: For anyone else trying to replicate this in Google, the tab press apparently has to be the first interaction with the search results page.  Do anything else first and it just cycles between tab stops conventionally.

Comment: @ChrisM `This would need to be performed upon every page navigation.` Would it though? Why not use arrow keys or page down? If I use the skip to content feature and then press tab I'm brought back to the top again anyways.

Comment: There's something ironic about spelling "accessibility" as "a11y".

Comment: @Clint Because if you can't see anything how do you know where you're paging down to? What is a "page"? Tabbing, in this context, moves between elements, potentially so that they can be spoken aloud. Sounds like you missed that this question is about _accessibility_.

Comment: @Clint This is for people for whom textual navigation is the primary or only way to interact with the content. They can't quickly skip over the top matter as a visual navigator would, and they can't simply scroll down as this is a visual/spatial metaphor. They may be able to arrow down if they are carat browsing but that is error prone and difficult for a complex site. Re: `If I use the skip to content feature and then press tab I'm brought back to the top again anyways.` - Not if it's done correctly, I would assume?

Comment: I can't get google to show me that button. All that happens is I get a dropdown of search suggestions, and then move to URL and Google-Logo. Is this a FF thing perhaps?

Comment: Its a FF combo with Mac OS I found out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704828/how-to-allow-keyboard-focus-of-links-in-firefox/11713537#11713537

Comment: @Luuklag on windows it works in both FF and Chrome, but only if you tab before doing anything else.  Once you start interacting with it like a sighted mouse/touchpad user it assumes you don't need help and hides the button.

Comment: @ChrisM Yeah, my assumption that arrows/paging would be preferred was pretty ignorant. Not sure about how the skip to content should work though, but that's what happens to me on both google and github. Maybe after getting to the content you would navigate another way? Not sure.