# Should There be Greater Accessibility in Stack Overflow's Site for Keyboard Users?

Tags: bug, accessibility

Here is a small list of accessibility concerns on our beloved site. These are important to address for more reasons than I can list here, but besides improving the site for all users and allowing them freedom of input, it also ensures that users with motor disabilities are not excluded from the site.

---

## Skip to Content Button

This was mentioned in [another meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382808/stack-overflow-should-add-a-skip-to-content-button-for-accessibility), so I will not go into depth on the issue.

Note that [WCAG Guideline 2.4.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/bypass-blocks.html) states:

> A mechanism is available to bypass blocks of content that are repeated
>   on multiple Web pages.

Though this is a Level A standard, the guideline also states that it is not necessary, even if useful and advised.

---

## Keyboard Inaccessibility

According to WCAG 2.1 [Guideline 2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/keyboard.html), the site's main content and functionality should be operable through keyboard:

> All functionality of the content is operable through a keyboard
>   interface without requiring specific timings for individual keystrokes

This is a Level A guideline. Here are places I have found inaccessible through keyboard alone:

### Site Wide: Footer

**Repro**: Goto [any page with a footer](https://stackoverflow.com/) > Navigate to the footer > Attempt to Access the "Mobile" or "Disable Responsiveness" tags under the "STACK OVERFLOW" heading by keyboard alone.

**Problem**: due to not actually being links, lacking href attributes, they are not added to the tabindex.

[image: The footer on most every page on the site. The two pseudo-links in red are inaccessible by keyboard.]

**Possible Solution:** add `tabindex="0"` attributes to each of them.

### Site Wide: Inconsistent Navbar

**Repro:** Observe the differences between, say, the [Company/About page](https://stackoverflow.com/company) (/about redirects to /company) or [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10442109/seraphendipity) versus the [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) *when the browser width is below 640px*.

**Problem**: Some pages have an "Help Center and other Resources" button in the navbar, others do not. This seems to be based both on as well as your browser width, creating an inconsistent experience.

[image: Now you see me, question mark in navbar on users page.]

[image: Now you don't, no question mark in navbar on Help page.]

[image: Now you see me again on the same page, but only when the browser is greater than 640px.]

**Possible Solution:** <s>It seems the intent was "if the page's content has a button or link to ask a question, remove it from the navbar. While a neat feature, it does not take that much room to keep the question mark there, and changing the navbar based on the page's content is inconsistent. Consider [the Help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help): why does it remove the question button? As [this poster put](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345318/the-ask-question-button-must-be-easily-accessible), for blind users, it may seem confusing to find the "Ask Question" button, especially if it changes depending on the page. Keep the Ask Question buttons on each page as you will, but keep it on the navbar at all times, as it is a crucial feature.</s>

These are somewhat important not only to allow consistent navigation, but it can also feel disorienting, almost akin to gas lighting, for users who rely on screen readers or voice over to navigate pages to have pages change their order (recall many users with alternative accessibility usually view pages as a linear path -- this is making the path to the main content shrink and expand on near arbitrary conditions from their viewpoint based on the page).

As a commenter pointed out, this is the "Help Center and other Resources" button, making it even weirder that its removed from some pages and not others, as it doesn't seem to have a particular rhyme or reason. This also means that the only workaround for keyboard users to access help information:

1. Know to go to a page where it is always active (requires guesswork or prior knowledge)
2. Expand the browser to at least 640px to activate it (requires guesswork or prior knowledge)
3. Find the resources of the pseudo-button through a series of links (game: go and try to find each of those links by clicking through the links in the footer and around the site; no search bar, as presumably a newer user would not know what to search for)

This is the  WCAG 2.1 [Guideline 3.2.3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-navigation.html) (Level AA) states:

> Navigational mechanisms that are repeated on multiple Web pages
>   within a set of Web pages occur in the same relative order each time
>   they are repeated, unless a change is initiated by the user.

Additionally, note that this issue is not as important as some others -- while it creates an inconsistent and somewhat sloppy effect, and may cause confusion for screen reader users if they are used to tabbing 18 times to get to content to suddenly have to use 17 on random pages, this issue does not significantly alter the ability of such users to reach core site features, only their ability to access help information more easily.

### Asking a Question

**Repro:** Goto [Questions/Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

**Problem**: The navigation menu is not available by keyboard.

[image]

**Possible Solution:** Due to the lack of a "Skip to Content" button, it is arguably better that there are not an additional five links to tab through. However, these are still functionalities that a keyboard user would like, either to review/edit their content or skip past the pages they cannot access right now (such as the below "Great!" page). As such, adding it to the tabindex order is necessary.

It may be worth considering either implementing them as either radio buttons or pseudo-radio buttons with `role` and `aria` attributes, such that users can tab to the sub menu, scroll through it with arrow keys, or tab to go to the content.

### Asking a Question: Type-->"Great!" Page

**Repro:** Goto [Questions/Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) > Select "I have a question about some code" > Select/Click "Next" pseudo-button > Attempt to select the "Next" or "Previous" pseudo-buttons using only keyboard control

**Problem:** The issue seems to be that these two a tags are actually disjointed children of the "Use traditional mode" a tag.

[image: The pseudo-buttons are children of the "Use traditional mode" link.]

**Possible Solution:** This likely can be fixed by simply making them siblings (resulting in a [more semantic DOM](https://medium.com/adalab/the-importance-of-semantic-html-78e74fb75ff0)) and adding a `tabindex="0"` attribute.

Not necessarily an accessibility concern, but it is troubling that these elements are a tag links, whereas on other subpages, such as the below "Tags", they are buttons. It would fix both the accessibility issue and be a cleaner solution to implement these similarly to the others.

### Asking a Question: Tags Page

**Repro:** Goto [Questions/Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) > Select "Tags" in the sub navigation menu at the top

**Problem:** The Search bar has a tabindex of 103...

[image: Tags Page, confusing tab index order.]

Which creates a non-meaningful tabindex order. Notably, the tab starts at the Tags input bar, then jump back to the header links, then down to the "Previous" and "Next" buttons (which are actual buttons here, not pseudo buttons as on the initial /questions/ask page -- I am not sure why the style and HTML elements are switching every page).

**Possible Solution:** This can be solved by either adding tabindex values to the button elements to have the content all semantically aligned in tabindex order (not advised), or by removing the tabindex of the Tag input bar to allow it to be part of the natural flow of the page (if it does not automatically join the tabindex, setting the attribute `tabindex="0"` will do). If there is a "Skip to Content" button, it will allow a quick jump to this element, removing the need of the unnatural tabindex.

### Asking a Question: Title

Same problem and solution as the above "Tags" with its titlebar.

### Asking a Question: Description

**Repro:** Goto [Questions/Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) > Select "Description" in the sub navigation menu at the top

**Problem:** Tab skips directly to content. This is arguably quite useful, especially considering that no "Skip to Content" button exists, however it also may throw off accessibility users who are used to tabbing immediately to the header each page -- it's inconsistent. Recall WCAG 2.1 [Guideline 3.2.3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-navigation.html)

Additionally, The sub-menu buttons ("Link", "Images", etc.) are not accessible at all by keyboard.

**Possible Solution**: Remove the tabindex that causes the tab to go directly to it, and let it rest naturally in the DOM. You can have similar functionality (quickly getting to content) in a "Skip to Content" button.
Additionally add the sub-menu buttons tothe tab-index order, or re-implement them in such a way they fall naturally into the tab-index order (such as a button).

### Asking a Question: Review

**Repro:** Goto [Questions/Ask Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) > Select "Review" in the sub navigation menu at the top

**Problem:** Suffers the same problem as the "Description" -- Skips to content in contrast to most pages on the site, and the sub-menu is inaccessible.

### Asking a Question: Traditional Mode

**Repro:** Goto the [Unguided Question Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false)

**Problem:** This one is not bad by any means, mainly because all of the core features of the page are at least usable by keyboard users, if they know what they are doing.

However, it fails in the same areas as the guided mode: it skips to content directly, creating confusing navigation where you must go through the entire top nav bar to get from "Post Your Question" to the "Answer your own question" checkbox directly below it.

[image: Users must press tab at least 18 times to get between these two elements.]

Additionally, though all functionality in the body is available with markup, the pseudo-buttons in the body sub-menu are not accessible by keyboard.

**Possible Solution:** As stated, removing all `tabindex` attributes or setting them to `0` would work wonders. The pseudo-buttons either need to be reimplemeneted or have a tabindex value. A possible alternative to allow them to be used without requiring several tabs more to get to the body would be to add a pseuod-radio button style to them, where you can tab to the submenu and select the elements with arrow keys.

---

Author's Note: First meta post, so am not entirely sure if these constitute a "bug" or "feature request", as I'm not sure Stack Overflow has made statements guaranteeing accessibility. There are likely other issues, however I think with these fixes it will go a long way to improving the site's usability for those who have trouble clicking through everything. It makes it much harder for impaired or disabled web developers to get questions and answers they need when they cannot readily or easily access content.

Stack Overflow is a great site and I have yet to meet a programmer to NOT use it near daily, so acting to create an accessible site may go a long way in not only improving the QoL for disabled users and devs on this site, but perhaps influence the many devs who use this site to pay attention to others who choose not or cannot access the computer in the "standard" way.

P.S. Random other thing I noticed: the "A

Comment: 3.2.3 also states: "Items are considered to be in the same relative order even if other items are inserted or removed from the original order.". Imho, this means that removing the ask question button is fine.

Comment: @BDL Indeed. It's also only a Level AA requirement and not near as much an issue as not being able to access some elements as in the other examples. However, I'm trying to think in the shoes of someone who must use a screen reader/keyboard. I found that even with sight I quickly got a certain rythmn when visiting pages -- 16 tabs to get to the main content for instance. Then I go to another page and its 15 tabs instead -- unless my browser is wide, then it adds the Q mark again so its 16 tabs. It seems sort of messy. But it is fine for the most part, even if inconsistent.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327943/1079354.  My take on this is that the team will *likely* address certain WCAG standards *violations*, but may not implement a lot of the nice-to-haves which seems to be what your post is predominately about.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, most of it are just nice to haves for accessibility and keyboard users -- they can still use the site, even if at reduced capacity/speed/ease. However, the biggest issue is that the "Guided Question" is completely blocked from keyboard-only usage, namely through the "Great!" page issue, ie a mouse MUST be used at least at some points, and they must have prior knowledge of markdown and Stack Overflow's use of it and know to go to the traditional input method in order to ask a question.
Still, these arent entirely crucial, hence why Im debating marking it as a suggestion instead.

Comment: @Seraphendipity You referred to 'an "Ask Question" button in the navbar,' but circled an image of the "Help Center" button. Is it mis-labelled for assistive technologies?

Comment: Downvoted, not because the suggestion is bad but because I personally think (most) other issues should have higher priority.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Huh, is that a legitimate way in which downvotes are used here? I wasn't aware. When looking at a downvoted question, is there no way then to differentiate between the community disagreeing with the proposition, and the community agreeing with it, but thinking it's low priority?

Comment: @pushkin Usually comments under the question give an idea about that, highly voted comments about post problem or disagreeing with the proposal give a fair clue, the [Meta-help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) state "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: @Tensibai Sure, but Dennis isn't disagreeing with the change. He's just saying it's not that important right now. I wonder if SO would not implement a feature request, because it's heavily down-voted, when in reality, people support the change, but it just wasn't important at one time or another.

Comment: @Pushkin The downvote tooltip says that one of the reasons is "This post is not useful." If someone thinks that something else should have higher priority, that's equivalent to saying that other things are more important than it, so it's completely valid to downvote for that reason, since with everything else that needs to be done, it's not useful to focus on this request. (Note I disagree, I think this is very useful and one of the most important features we could be developing, hence I upvoted).

Comment: @pushkin I slightly disagree that the vote should be tied to something else than the post itself, external consideration like "there's more important things to fix" should not weight toward the usefulness/interest of the post

Comment: Fixing the tabindex order problem will be fixed in 6-8, but what will the unit be? Hopefully not years.

Comment: @Tensibai Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying - maybe I wasn't clear

Comment: @pushkin Yep, I had understood your comment as "It's normal to downvote because it's less important than other FR waiting even if the FR is interesting" :)